# Will this PDE reach steady state?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

I'm not great at maths and have hence been struggling on this for a while. I have been trying to find the numerical solution to the following, however I am not convinced it will actually reach steady state:

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{r\rho}\left(\tau+r \frac{\partial\tau}{\partial r}\right),\quad \text{where}\quad \tau = P\left(\mu+b \sqrt{\dfrac{\rho_g}{P}}\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}\right)$$
Could anyone please advise if this will reach steady state over time, as so far in all of my attempts it has grown indefinitely.

For those who are interested it is the momentum equation in cylindrical coordinates, which I am trying to propagate to steady state in MATLAB.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's important to work with "minimal examples" when asking for help like this. In your case it looks to me like it comes down to $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \frac{c_1 + c_2 \partial_r V}{r} + c_3 \partial_{rr} V$ where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are (all positive?) constants.

Comment: To clarify: is $\tau=P(\text{stuff})$ intended as $P$ a function of stuff, or $P$ times stuff? (I would presume the latter because the former would have $P$ a function of itself, but the notation is alas ambiguous.)

Comment: Most importantly, what are variables and what are constants? Is $V = V(r, t)$, or does it depend on other variables as well? I presume $P$ is pressure. Is it constant or time-varying? Finally, you use funny letters for derivatives. Are they all full derivatives $d/dt$ or partial derivatives $\partial / \partial t$. I would assume the latter, but e.g. in fluid dynamics they frequently use the former, so one has to be careful

Comment: Another important point: What are your boundary conditions? If you want both $\tau$ and $V$ to be well-behaved at the origin, for instance, then the only option for the steady state is $\tau=0$ everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. @Ian yes that is correct, with c1, c2, and c3 all being positive constants.

Comment: @Semiclassical tau = P(stuff) is intended to be P times (stuff), apologies for the ambiguity. My boundary conditions at r = 0 is a nonzero positive constant and r = R (being the length of the body) is 0. I was hoping that both V and tau would decay radially from the boundary, but it seems that will not be the case as the values of tau should be nonzero. Thanks.

Comment: @Aleksejs Fomins The system is only dependant on r and t, and pressure is constant. Apologies for the notation, they are partial derivatives. Thanks.

Comment: If $\tau(r=0)$ is some nonzero constant, then I don't think a steady state is possible. If $V_s$ is time-independent, then you have $\tau=-r d\tau/dt$ which solves to $\tau=A/r$. But this blows up at $r=0$ unless $A=0$, in which case $\tau=0$ identically.

Comment: A comment about notation: the symbol for partial derivatives is $\partial$ (\partial), not $\delta$ (\delta).

Answer (score 1):

1. It can be observed that the equation can be rewritten as

$$\frac{A}{r} + \frac{B}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + B \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r^2} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$$

Where $A$ and $B$ are some constants. We will have a look at the steady state solution of this equation, namely $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = 0$

$$\frac{A}{r} + \frac{B}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} + B \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r^2} = 0$$

By use of black magic or otherwise, we will find the partial solution

$$V = V_{hom} + V_{part} = V_{hom} -\frac{A}{B}r$$

Finally we will solve the homogeneous equation

$$\frac{B}{r}\frac{\partial V_{hom}}{\partial r} + B \frac{\partial^2 V_{hom}}{\partial r^2} = 0$$

Assuming $B$ and $r$ non-zero, we will simplify the equation as

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \biggl (r \frac{\partial V_{hom}}{\partial r} \biggr) = 0$$

Integrating this equation two times will give us

$$V_{hom} = K_1 \log r + K_2$$

To the best of my understanding we have to set $K_1 = 0$, otherwise our solution approaches $-\infty$ at the origin. So the total steady state solution is

$$V = K_2 - \frac{A}{B}r$$

for some constant $K_2$.

**Edit**: Thanks to suggestion of @Semiclassical, there is an additional point to consider. Given the above steady state solution for $V$, its derivative

$$\frac{dV}{dr} = -\frac{A}{B} = const$$

Is constant and hence

$$\tau = \tau(\frac{dV}{dr}) = \tau(const) = const$$

This means that $\frac{d\tau}{dr} = 0$. When we plug in both results into the very original equation, we find that

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \frac{\tau}{r\rho} = 0$$

This last equation cannot be satisfied for all $r$ by selecting $K_2$.

Hence we are forced to conclude that there are no steady state solutions to this equation, regardless of the boundary condition (that is, assuming that infinite boundary conditions are unphysical).

Comment: To underline a point I made in comments: If $V=K_2-Ar/B$, then $\partial V/\partial r$ is a constant and therefore $\tau$ is as well. But then we also must have $\tau = -r d\tau/dr=0$. So if the logarithmic solution to $V$ is excluded, then the only possible steady state has $\tau=0$.

Comment: @Semiclassical You are right, sorry I missed it